Who is penalized when attempting to secure a person with Knots?
BWGR 280:

Knots Per/Agi
Knots is the knowledge of many rope ties vital to sailors to keep a ship running.
Obstacles: ... Securing a person: Knots vs Escape Artist or Power at double obstacle penalty...

This sentence is kind of ambiguous. Is the knotter penalized, or is the victim penalized? Is the victim only penalized when testing Power, because it's a stat? Or is the victim always penalized?

In Burning Wheel if you are attempting to do something and you do not have the skill for it then you can test its root stat against double the Ob. However Escape Artist is a skill tied to agility so if you wanted to use Escape Artist without having it you would have to roll against double the obstacle. There are no rules for what happens when two double obstacles stack. Based on the fact that there are no rules and specific rules aren't written in the text it can be concluded that it is 'Escape Artist or (Power against Ob*2).
